# Send & Delete in Gmail

Tags: gmail, delete

Is there any way to add **"Send & Delete"** button in Gmail like **"Send & Archive"** which can be enabled in Labs? Any add-ons, extensions or Greasemonkey script will do.

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I want this too.  Al, asking "why?" is like saying user-friendly means "there is only one use-case user".  Anyway, Are Google Lab products client or server based?  Otherwise, I can give it a go.

Comment: Known request on Google Labs Suggestion group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/%22Send$20$26$20Delete%22|sort:relevance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing in Labs to do this at this time.

Depending on what you're after, you might be able to get close using filters. Create a filter that looks for a particular string in the content ("Contains:"). Make the string something innocuous that no one would ever think to put in a message (something like `///d\\\`). Then set your filter to delete any such message.

When you send a message with that string in it the message will get labelled "Trash" (as if you'd deleted it yourself).

Two possible complications

- If the recipient replies and quotes your "tag" the message will go straight to Trash. If they don't it won't
- If you use this to reply to a message, the reply will go to Trash, but the original won't. It doesn't delete the whole thread

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish these may or may not be a problem.